# Problematic git workflow deleted other peoples work

Tags: git, git-workflow

I am fairly new to git and I am trying to figure out why my workflow deleted the work that other people have done. The workflow is as follows:

1. I am working on some bugs on my local master branch. (I know I should be using a different branch but in this case I havent)
2. Commit the changes that I've done for these bugs but still have other work that is not ready to be committed
3. When it comes to pushing the fixes for these bugs I do a stash to save all my other work and then pull from the remote. (at this stage my assumption was that I am inline with the work that others have done and the current head is inline with the remote)
4. I then apply the stash and push assuming that only my committed changes will be pushed

Unfortunately this deleted work that others have done.

So my question is:

1. If 'stash apply' is essentially a merge why/how did this happen? Shouldnt 'stash apply' merge my local changes to what pull returned (i.e. other peoples work)?

   2. Does stash actually stash all your committed files or only just the stagged ones? Because if so I understand that I should have done a rebase instead of a plain pull

Heres what the relevant graph looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. In a way `stash apply` can indeed be seen as a kind of merge. But it doesn't create a merge commit, so it would be more correct to consider that it just applies your stashed changes on the top of the current commit.
2. `stash` stashes every modifications (whether you `git add`ed them or not)

That being said, what you describe is rather strange: unless you forced the push (`git push -f` or `git push --force`), git won't let you push a commit that would delete an existing remote commit, so you can't delete other people's work.

Unless you mean that you've partially reverted their work when you applied the stash. In this case it means their commit is still their, so it's definitely not lost (you just need for example to revert your own commit).

Finally: even if you deleted their commit, and pushed forced, it may not the end yet:

- your colleagues might still have their own commits in their local clone
- or if you did your manipulations not too long ago, the "lost" commit might not be garbage collected yet, so it might still be recoverable (see for example http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/01/17/restoring-lost-commits.html)

Comment: I didnt need to force the push and luckily we realised quickly that files were missing so we resolved by doing a hard reset to the point right before my push. I just dont understand how on earth my push deleted their files.

Comment: Btw I'm not sure what you mean by 'partially reverted their work'. They had created new files and pushed and these files were gone after my push. However we managed to get them back when we reset to the hash before my push

Comment: 'partially reverted their work' means for example 'removing their new files'. According to your description of what you did, I don't understand either how it could have happened. You may try `git show <your_commit's_sha1>` to ensure your commit actually deleted these files

Comment: No I'm talking about whole files. Which after they did a pull they disappeared from their local as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your sequence was...

```
git pull
git stash apply
git push
```

...with no intervening commit, then it can't be the stash.  Here's why.

Let's reconstruct what you said you did and what the repository looked like...

> 1. I am working on some bugs on my local master branch. (I know I should be using a different branch but in this case I haven't)

You'd start looking something like this:

```
A - B [origin/master] [master]
```

> 2. Commit the changes that I've done for these bugs but still have other work that is not ready to be committed.

```
A - B [origin/master] - D - E [master]
```

D and E here are your bug fixes and you're doing the normal add/commit process.  The other work is sitting in your index or on disk, not represented here.

> 3. When it comes to pushing the fixes for these bugs I do a stash to save all my other work...

`git stash save` puts the stash hanging off your current commit.

```
A - B [origin/master] - D - E [master]
                             \
                              F [stash@{0}]
```

> and then pull from the remote. (at this stage my assumption was that I am inline with the work that others have done and the current head is inline with the remote)

A pull is a fetch plus a merge.  After the fetch, if there was work pushed to the remote by someone else, your repo will look like this:

```
      G - H - I [origin/master]
     /
A - B - D - E [master]
             \
              F [stash@{0}]
```

Then origin/master is merged into master.

```
      G - H - I [origin/master]
     /          \
A - B - D - E -  J [master]
             \
              F [stash@{0}]
```

> I then apply the stash and push assuming that only my committed changes will be pushed

Apply is not a merge like `git merge` which merges histories, it's more like `git cherry-pick` which *applies* a patch.  It will take the diff between E and F and patch J with it.  There may be conflicts which you have to resolve.  Git may silently get it wrong.

It's academic because `git stash apply` doesn't commit, that's up to you.  So long as you didn't commit after the apply, there should be no change to your repository.  When you push, you're pushing D, E (your bug fixes) and J (the merge point with origin/master).

It's entirely possible that something you did in D and E confused the merge with G, H and I, so J would be where I'd start looking.  I would do a `git log --stat --decorate --graph J` to see what got added and deleted and when (--decorate and --graph will produce those lines and labels I've been using for better understanding of the repository).

You can recover J by looking at `git reflog` which is the history of all the commands which have moved HEAD and what ID it was pointing to.  Git garbage collection is very blasé, and it will probably still be there for weeks.

Comment: The graph was a good suggestion so decided to download a tool and get a  better look at it. I feel a little thick but im still not sure how to interpret it though. I edited the post to include the picture.

Comment: @mixkat Which commit deleted the files? It was probably a mistaken merge, but I can't tell what got git confused enough to think it needed to delete files just from the graph. Did you touch those files at all in your commits?

Comment: It was the one done at 13.58 by me and no I havent touched the files at all. Its a mystery

Comment: @mixkat Oh, that's just a regular commit. Sorry to say, but it wasn't the merge. You deleted the files somehow. What commands and flags do you run to add and commit? `git commit -a`?  `git add -A`? Does your shell history go back far enough to check?

Comment: Unfortunately the commit was done from within netbeans so I am not really sure how it does it.